# How do I add VCBuild.exe to Windows 10 w/o Visual Studio

Tags: windows-10, node.js, visual-c++

So I am trying to compile gyp and it wants to call VCBuild.exe apparently...

```
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [C:\...\node_module
s\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\no
de_modules\utf-8-validate\build\binding.sln]
```

So I install the .Net framework using this but when I go to the cmd line I get...

```
'VCBuild.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

so what am I missing what do I need to get VCBuild without Visual Studio?

Comment: I just entered `VCBuild.exe`

Comment: I realize what it means but I don't even think that framework will install on Win 10. I tried that already

Comment: Where would that be?

Comment: Also this was Windows 10 so I am not sure how well Vs 2005 will run and I don't have a copy so those are no-go options.

Comment: So I have to install an entire IDE to get this tool?

Comment: How could I be more verbose I said right in the question without Visual Studio and on Win 10

Comment: So how do I get that component without installing Vs2005 I still haven't found a download location. I tried installing the Win10 SDK

Comment: Really? Silly that an "Open Source" project would require a proprietary library.

Comment: And I don't have the energy to "fool" it into using make

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`npm install -g windows-build-tools`

ran in an administration window:

> ```
> Starting installation...
> Launched installers, now waiting for them to finish.
> This will likely take some time - please be patient!
> Waiting for installers... -Successfully installed Python 2.7
> Waiting for installers... /Successfully installed Visual Studio Build Tools.
> ```

Comment: Great, now I have multiple Python installs when all I wanted was VCBuild.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me - running Windows 7 Enterprise

Comment: It took more than 15 minutes to complete, but worked eventually!

Comment: This solved part of the node-gyp problems, still missing "VCBuild" though.

Comment: An additional `choco install -y vcbuildtools` fixed my build environment.

Comment: Windows 10, works. Just takes so long you wonder is it stuck or not, keep waiting.

Comment: Windows 10 worked; it found my existing Python and didn't install a new one. Yes takes a long time at the end.

Comment: why it tells me "is not recognized as an internal or external command" for both choco and npm? I am on windows 10, calling the command from administrator command prompt

Answer (score 5):

(This answer comes from comments above from @s.meijer. But I think it deserves to be an answer by its own.)

Run `choco install vcbuildtools` will install `vcbuild` that satisfies `npm` build needs on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just posting this in case it saves anyone some time.

I tried all the answers I could find regarding this issue and they didn't work, ie:

```
// running powershell as administrator  
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools 

choco install vcbuildtools
```

The only thing that made `"VCBuild.exe"` errors go away was installing:

```
NET Framework 2.0 Software Development Kit (SDK)
```

The installation was a bit weird, I ran the `.exe` file and nothing seemed to happen but, judging by the fact that the install error messages went away, apparently it worked and was installed.

Comment: Not sure if this really helped, but I'm going to vote up. Seems like `windows-build-tools` didn't fully help, and the .NET 2.0 SDK is silent (no UI) which is confusing. After 2-3 minutes, the rebuilding worked.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer was staring me in the face... You can't :-(

I found the steps to compile on the node-gyp [Readme.md](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp)

It does in fact require VS2015 for Windows which sucks because

[image]

Comment: Ended up being 16GBs

Comment: VC++ on its own is >3GB though.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I was trying to run an AngularJs application (requiring Node.js 6x) in an Node.js 12x env.
Downgrading my version of Node.js made this go away.
TIP: If you need to flip between Node versions, look at http://nvm.sh

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).